# Read Excel 2.0 to datatable

Tags: c#, .net, excel, oledb

I have an .xls file (Excel 2.0 1988 year format), which should be converted it into C# datatable. I tried to use an oledb and odbc providers and got no result.

So how can I read it programmatically?

Oledb connection string that I've tried out:

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Extended Properties='Excel 2.0; HDR=NO';Data Source=mypath;
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Extended Properties='Excel 12.0; HDR=NO';Data Source=mypath;
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Extended Properties='Excel 8.0; HDR=NO';Data Source=mypath;
```

Comment: Check out the [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) library. It's one of the easiest packages to read and write XLS and XLSX files in any environment.

Comment: What happens when you try the connection strings list. Have you tried adding IMEX to the connection string? See the following for more on connection string and IMEX http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37055/Working-with-MS-Excel-xls-xlsx-Using-MDAC-and-Oled

Comment: I got an Exception with message "External table is not in the expected format.".(I got message in Russian so the original message in Eng may looks a bit differently)